# Search MySQL Database Based Soley on Date rather than Date and Time

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datetime

I have a table which holds the datetime information of creation of that row. However I am trying to count the number of creations per day, in a given time frame.

```
select count(*), DateCreated FROM Stories WHERE DateCreated BETWEEN '2013-03-28' AND '2014-01-07' group by DateCreated;
```

However, because I have them grouped by DateCreated, I get a count of 1 for everything, despite knowing that multiple stories were created on the same day; the time portion of the datetime field makes each one unique enough to group by though.

Is there a way I might modify my query to ignore the time portion of the datetime and use soley the date for distinction in the group by?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
    NumPerDay   = count(*), 
    DateCreated = cast(DateCreated as Date)
FROM 
    Stories 
WHERE 
    cast(DateCreated as Date) BETWEEN '2013-03-28' AND '2014-01-07' 
GROUP BY 
    cast(DateCreated as Date)
```

Or

```
SELECT
    NumPerDay   = count(*), 
    DateCreated = DATE(DateCreated)
FROM 
    Stories 
WHERE 
    Date(DateCreated) BETWEEN '2013-03-28' AND '2014-01-07' 
GROUP BY 
    DATE(DateCreated)
```

Or if casting Datecolumn in where clause prevents use of an available index:

```
SELECT
    NumPerDay   = count(*), 
    DateCreated = DATE(DateCreated)
FROM 
    Stories 
WHERE 
    DateCreated BETWEEN '2013-03-28 00:00:00' AND '2014-01-07 23:59:59.999' 
GROUP BY 
    DATE(DateCreated)
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! Casting in MySQL... new to me but makes perfect sense! Will accept as soon as time allows!

Answer (score 0):

Just cast `DateCreated` to `DATE` like below

```
SELECT
     count(*), DATE(DateCreated) 
FROM 
     Stories 
WHERE 
     DateCreated BETWEEN '2013-03-28' AND '2014-01-07' 
GROUP BY
    DATE(DateCreated);
```

Comment: Don't know dude... I'm just reviewing this post.  What do you want me to say... you answer is fantastic!

Comment: @Rico Ok, now it will not show up in low quality post list. Thanks for  pointing out.